# Do typical NNs generate new features by applying some function to the input?

Tags: neural-networks, feature-selection, conv-neural-network, feature-engineering

The toy network on `playground.tensorflow.org` has the option to generate new features by applying some function based on the input, e.g. with the inputs $X_1, X_2$ it generates new inputs $X_1X_2, sin(X_1), sin(X_2), etc$. This leads to faster convergence of the NN when used.

I could not find however typical NNs using the same technique, e.g. image processing CNNs have 3 channels for RGB. However, they usually do not generate new channels based on applying some function to the input.

Why is this the case? I did not find any papers about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the general approach in neural networks, especially in deep learning, is to let the NN learn to create useful features by themselves, instead of us engineering them. Especially in computer vision problems, the networks are made deeper (e.g. more layers) and wider (e.g. more filters) to learn more sophisticated representations of the input images.

Comment: Some features however where the network designer suspects that they may be useful (e.g. $sin(X_1)$ for periodic $X_1$) could still be input into the network... I do not think that generating something similar to $sin(x)$ (or another periodicity recognizing function) is trivial for NNs.

Comment: Yes, it can be useful and such features can be sometimes hard to generate by a NN. However, you'll also see the opposite situation. While training NNs over images, you may see that the first layer of the NN constitutes edge detectors. You could do this by yourself, but NNs can do it as well. The thing is, deep learning doesn't advocate not using additional features but, especially in some problems, it's not the philosophy.